# Protocol required error while installing magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

Please help me to solve below error I am getting while installing Magento 1.9 in my local system (I think I have added the right URL only), it is so ridiculous :(

[image]

Comment: just use "http://localhost/m1-1.9.3.8/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same error before few days while installation in my local,

Inspect that input and you will find it has class="required-entry validate-url input-text validation-failed" class.

Just remove "validate-url" class from your inspected input and click on continue.

[image]

This will solve your error.

Comment: I could not find this class in my input

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox but does that matter?

Comment: I have added screenshot in my comment

Comment: I got your point, and it worked..thanks !

Comment: welcome..if you find the answer useful then make it mark so that it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of this error there possible 2 solutions in my mind.

> 1). Create virtual host for your magento.
>
> 2). Core hack !! Inspect on
> this input field and than remove class `base-secure-validate-url`
> class (Something like I ain't sure) .

Check Image Remove selected class and than go ahead.[image]

Than execute setup wizard Ahead it will work.

Comment: can you help me to create virtual host?

Comment: Check now I've added screen for core hack !!

Comment: can I give right marks to two answers ? and how?

Answer (score 1):

Put http://127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and try